# Drupal 7 Instagram Drupgram oauth issue

Tags: drupal, oauth, instagram

I am using Drupal 7, Drupagram module + oauth module (oauth 1,0) for  retrieving user recent media.

It suddenly stop working on February 2015. Did something change on this  period ? maybe some  deprecated functionality?

Comment: Can you state the nature of the "stopped working"?

Comment: This is a non-programming question, so likely unfit for Stack Overflow. Try asking on drupagram issue queue or on Drupal Answer (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: as "stopped working" I mean: when  I call  cthe curl function i t doesn't return nothing,  just a timeout.